# Use keyboard shortcut for previous and next pagination with jQuery

Tags: jquery, keyboard, pagination

I created a gallery in jQuery and I need to use left and right keys of the keyboard to get the previous and next URL.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must catch keypress event on the `document` object.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
       // do something when left arrow is pressed
       return false;
    }
});
```

Character codes:

37 - left

39 - right

40 - down

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).keydown(function (evt) { alert(evt.which); });
```

Now you can find out the codes for 'left' and 'right' (just by pressing them) and use them ;).

Comment: They are 37 (left) and 39 (right) (I just tested it). Now you can do actions like this:
$(document).keydown(function(evt) { if (evt.which == 37) { alert('Left pressed!'); }});